# Immaculately clean litter box versus leaving a tiny amount: any rigid science?

Tags: cats, toilet-training

I have read several questions here regarding [cats](/questions/tagged/cats) and [toilet-training](/questions/tagged/toilet-training) as well as the [ASPCA](https://www.aspca.org/pet-care/virtual-pet-behaviorist/cat-behavior/litter-box-problems) and others.  I have found that most agree that a cat who is making mistakes in this area should have the box cleaned as frequently and thoroughly as possible, lest the cat think, "I don't want to poop or pee over there, that stinks!"  But there are a few, especially when it regards young kittens who are still learning, who suggest it can help to leave a small amount behind, so as to suggest, "Hmm.  There is some poop and pee here.  That must be what this box is for."

Before marking this question as "inviting opinion or debate" please understand that I am hoping to get bona-fide-expert answers, or at least from someone who can point me to hard scientific evidence to support either point of view.  Typical internet searches generally only lead me to magazine-like articles without citations.

[  While not needed to answer this question, my personal context is a 3-month old kitten, just one week home from a shelter, who so far is mostly going *next to* the box, not *inside* it.  I am using the suggestions I have read, and I think things are improving slowly.  I always quickly clean-up whatever I find, and do my best Oscar winning performances to act disgusted at the horrible messes outside the box, and bubbly with glee at the nice presents inside the box, always directing the acting at the matter, never the kitten.  ]

Comment: I don't think there has ever been an immaculately clean litter box except ones that have never been used or _possibly_ in a lab. There are specific medical situations where a covered litterbox may be a problem, but I haven't seen any real evidence that most cats find a normal litterbox to be a problem even if using old-style clay litter and letting it go several. days between cleanings.

Comment: @keshlam:  I know what you're saying- perhaps "assiduously" or "intensively" would have been better than "immaculately."  And a cat that is fully habituated and litter trained can tolerate a little laxness in having the litter scooped out.  But this question is about a cat that is just learning about litter.

Comment: Reasonably clean has worked just fine for decades.

Comment: For what it's worth, at least one manufacturer offered "training litter" which was lightly pre-scented with sterile (artificial?) cat pee, theoretically to help a young cat (or a feral just starting to live with people) realize what this is for. I have no evidence that it was anything more than a marketing gimmick.